# LINQ to Subsonic Left Outer Join

Tags: linq, linq-to-sql, orm, subsonic3

I have the following query:

```
var q = from x in content_item.All()
        join y in vendor.All() on x.Vendor_ID equals y.Vendor_ID into tmp
        from v in tmp.DefaultIfEmpty()
        select new { Z=x.Content_Item_Name,W=((v!=null)?v.Vendor_Name:"")};
```

when I type:

```
var items = q.ToList();
```

I got the following exception:

```
Expression of type 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1[Vamp.Models.content_item]' cannot be used for parameter of type 'System.Linq.IQueryable`1[Vamp.Models.content_item]' of method 'System.Linq.IQueryable`1[<>f__AnonymousType0`2[Vamp.Models.content_item,System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1[Vamp.Models.vendor]]] GroupJoin[content_item,vendor,Nullable`1,<>f__AnonymousType0`2](System.Linq.IQueryable`1[Vamp.Models.content_item], System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1[Vamp.Models.vendor], System.Linq.Expressions.Expression`1[System.Func`2[Vamp.Models.content_item,System.Nullable`1[System.UInt32]]], System.Linq.Expressions.Expression`1[System.Func`2[Vamp.Models.vendor,System.Nullable`1[System.UInt32]]], System.Linq.Expressions.Expression`1[System.Func`3[Vamp.Models.content_item,System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1[Vamp.Models.vendor],<>f__AnonymousType0`2[Vamp.Models.content_item,System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1[Vamp.Models.vendor]]]])'
```

Any idea?

Note: content_item.All() is IQueryable and vendor.All() is IQueryable

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorry I missed this question back when you asked it...

The left outer join syntax in SubSonic 3 is slightly different. I have a workaround posted as an answer to this question: [Subsonic 3.0 Left Join](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1136869/subsonic-3-0-left-join)

Answer (score 0):

Hi you need to do something like this, create a getter setter as followed:

```
public class ReturnProperty
{
      public string Z{ get; set; }
      public string W{ get; set; }

}
```

And Change your query like this:

```
var q = from x in content_item.All()
                join y in vendor.All() on x.Vendor_ID equals y.Vendor_ID into tmp
                from v in tmp.DefaultIfEmpty()
                select new ReturnProperty { Z=x.Content_Item_Name,W=((v!=null)?v.Vendor_Name:"")};
var items = q.ToList();
```

Hope this helps..

Comment: I searched the issue and it seems that is a bug in Subsonic