# What LINQ features are not supported with SubSonic 3?

Tags: linq, subsonic, subsonic3

What linq features are currently not supported in SS3?  Can't seem to find a list.

Ta,

Bob

Answer (score 1):

I think union is one feature not supported. I just ran into this last week, searched and found more info [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1044245/subsonic-3-union-possible).

Answer (score 0):

Also, you can't make an non-anonymous select in a custom object.  While

```
from elem in XCollection select new 
with {.customField = elem.someProperty}
```

works well, this doesn't:

```
from elem in XCollection select new CustomClass _
with {.customField = elem.someProperty}
```

Left joins are also unsupported.